# Service to retrieve all likes, +1, retrieves, etc

Tags: favorites

Is there any service out there to retrieve all the likes in Facebook or YouTube, favorites or retweets in Twitter, +1, etc...?

I know there's Yahoo! Pipes out there but even if it was possible with them I find them slow, there is also [Memolane](http://memolane.com/), but it logs everything, not just stuff I like.

Answer (score 2):

You can export your +1's (as well as Contacts, Circles, Stream, Picasa Web Albums, etc.) using [Google's Takeout menu](https://www.google.com/takeout/)

Comment: Facebook's **Download Your Information** option (under **Account Settings**) does creates (under **Profile**) a stripped down text list of the likes that appear on your Profile page but it does not seem to export likes to posts on _other_ walls.

Comment: But that's only a couple of the services via export option, not all of them combined. I am kind of looking for an aggregator to read them all at once. Does it exist?